# Docker Compose Version Error - Not Working/Started Working Randomly

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to launch docker-compose with yaml version 3.8, compose version 1.26.2, docker-engine 18.09.7. According to docker's website this should all work together on ubuntu 18.04 but im still getting the following error. I then did nothing for 10 minutes while writing this post and it started working again?

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yaml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
```

Have the following docker-compose: `docker-compose version`

```
docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31
docker-py version: 4.2.2
CPython version: 3.7.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
```

Have the following docker version: `sudo docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:38 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Aug 15 15:12:41 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Have the following docker-compose.yaml

```
version:                       '3.7'

services:

    word-similarity-search:
        build:                 word-similarity-search
        environment:
            DB_DATABASE:       $aws_db_database
        volumes:
            - ./word-similarity-search:/deploy
        ports:
            - 3080:3080

    generate_embeddings:
        build:                 item-similarity-search/generate_embeddings
        environment:
            DB_DATABASE:       $aws_db_database
        volumes:
            - ./item-similarity-search/generate_embeddings:/deploy
        ports:
            - 3081:3081

    search_similar_items:
        build:                 item-similarity-search/search_similar_items
        environment:
            DB_DATABASE:       $aws_db_database
        volumes:
            - ./item-similarity-search/search_similar_items:/deploy
        ports:
            - 3082:3082
        depends_on:
            - generate_embeddings

    person-similarity-search:
        build:                 person-similarity-search
        environment:
            DB_DATABASE:       $aws_db_database
        volumes:
            - ./person-similarity-search:/deploy
        ports:
            - 3083:3083

    recommendations:
        build:                 recommendations
        environment:
            DB_DATABASE:       $aws_db_database
        volumes:
            - ./recommendations:/deploy
        ports:
            - 3084:3084
        depends_on:
            - generate_embeddings
            - search_similar_items
            - person-similarity-search

    portainer:
        image:                 portainer/portainer
        command:               -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        restart:               always
        ports:
          - 3090:9000
          - 8000:8000
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          - portainer_data:/data

volumes:
  portainer_data:
```